# Phpstorm Hotkeys in XUbuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I have installed xubuntu 13.04 and PhpStorm 6.x.
But dont work hotkeys(not all). Dont work ctrl + a, ctrl + x, ctrl + v
Help me!